# import datasets dataset = datasets.load_dataset("samsum", split='train')

Tags: huggingface-datasets

> ConnectionError: Couldn't reach 'samsum' on the Hub

I can not download data from Hugging Face using `datasets.load_dataset`. I run this code in WSL-Ubuntu,
I do not know why I cannot download data.  Do I miss some something to configure?

This dataset is used to fine tune llama2 model locally.